# Как правильно: облапал или облапил?

Tags: выбор-слов

*Он облапил (облапал) ее бедра и ягодицы...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном предложении возможны обе формы:

***облапал*** (грубо ощупал или обнял/обхватил) или ***облапил*** (обнял/обхватил), это нужно определить по контексту.

Из словаря Кузнецова:

**ОБЛАПАТЬ,**  св. кого (что). Разг.-сниж. 1. Бесцеремонно, грубо **ощупать** чьё-л. тело. Его всего облапали. 2. **Неуклюже обхватить, обнять.** Облапал меня при случайной встрече. <**Облапить,** -плю, -пишь; св. кого. **=Облапать (2 зн.)**. Оставь её в покое, что ты её **облапил**!